# How to apply CSS style for getting shadow for text area

Tags: css, gwt

how to apply css style to get shadow for text area in GWT.
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following for just text.

```
.box{
text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #cfaecf;
filter: dropshadow(color=#cfaecf, offx=3, offy=3);
}
```

You can do the following for adding a shaddow to a text-area form - I think that is what you want.

```
<style type="text/css">
.box{
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px ##eee;
-moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px ##eee;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px ##eee;
}
</style>
<textarea class="box" rows="5"></textarea>
```

Also adding a border for non HTML5/CSS3 browsers:

```
<style type="text/css">
border-bottom:2px solid #000;
border-right:2px solid #000;
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Jse3N/

```
textarea {
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 0px #999;
}
```

**edit:** Sorry, you were talking about GWT. I don't know, whether it works there too.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```
<style>
    .textarea
    {        
     background: white;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    border-radius: 5px;

    color: #666;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: 150px;
    outline: none;
    height:25px;
    box-shadow:3px 3px 3px #96A1BD;

    }
</style>
```

add CssClass ="textarea" to your textbox

Try it.

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="address"  CssClass="textarea" runat="server" Width="450px" style="height: 55px"  TextMode="MultiLine"
       ></asp:TextBox>